# How can I create datasets for both the result sets from a stored procedure like above

Tags: reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that returns multiple result sets just as below

```
CREATE procedure Sp_getempdate
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EMPID, ENAME, JOB, SAL, DEPTID 
    FROM Sal_employee

    SELECT DEPT ID, DAME, COL 
    FROM Sal_Department--second result set
END
```

In SSRS, while creating a new report using VS 2017 I configured the stored procedure for data set. It creates the data set ONLY with the columns returned from the first result set. It does not identify the second result set.

How can I create datasets for both the result sets from a stored procedure like above

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one result set for the dataset per data source. I would recommend either joining your tables to produce one result set, and creating 2 datasets with different grouping. Or create another stored procedure, if you just have a simple select statement I would just use a view.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, SSRS will only access one recordset so you will either have to create 2 separate SPs or make some changes to your existing stored proc.

You could add a parameter that determines which dataset to return,

```
ALTER myProc (@rs int) AS 

....
....
    IF @rs 1 
        BEGIN
            SELECT EMPID, ENAME, JOB, SAL, DEPTID FROM Sal_employee
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT DEPT ID, DAME, COL FROM Sal_Department--second result set
        END
```

You can then just called the SP with the relevant parameter value for each of your datasets.